# is ANGULAR 2 UNIVERSAL production ready?

Tags: angular

Is angular 2 universal ready for production yet?
which is the best seed project to use?
is there any seed project which supports material ui?

what are the common issues faced?
we are about to rewrite an existing, large application.
we need to complete the project in a very short time,
we have decided to go with angular universal.
however not sure of its stability.
thanks

Comment: That depends on what "production ready" means for you, therefore this is an entirely opinion based question that should not be asked on StackOverflow.